# Experience with syncfusion flutter widget

Tags: flutter, calendar, syncfusion

I am new to flutter and would like to ask for some help.
I am trying to implement a booking system in my mobile app.
I was researching and found out a lot of people use   syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^19.1.58.
Do you think it is possible using that widget for the user to book appointment?

I will appreciate any help or materials I can have a look.

Comment: I hope this is what you are looking for - https://www.syncfusion.com/blogs/post/how-to-create-a-scheduling-application-using-flutter-event-calendar.aspx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am working on a new mobile app. The main aim of the app is to book appointments.

After some research, I found out about syncfusion calendar widget. 

Do you think using that widget might help me to achieve my aim?

I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xbH-jFi6TM0&t=1400s&ab_channel=Syncfusion%2CInc

It helped me a lot however it does not fully cover what I want.

At the end my question is, is it possible when the user opens the syncfusion widget and clicks on a date to book an appointment? Is there a better solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your requirement by using the "OnTap" callback from the Flutter Calendar. To add the appointments when tapping the date in the calendar, refer to the following link in our KB documentation: https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/12300/how-to-add-the-appointments-using-the-ontap-callback-in-the-flutter-calendar

To add appointments to the Flutter Calendar, refer to this link:

https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/appointments

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).